# I wanted to do unban command in discord.NET and i do it like this, but its not working. Can you help me?

Tags: c#, discord.net

This is the code:

[Command("unban")]
[RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.BanMembers, ErrorMessage = "You must be minimally Alfa role. Then you can do this.")]

```
    public async Task UnBanMember(IGuildUser user = null)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            await ReplyAsync("Guy you should write here who.");
            return;
        }

        await Context.Guild.RemoveBanAsync(user);

        ITextChannel InfoChannel = Context.Client.GetChannel(781145775467135006) as ITextChannel;
        var EmbedBuilder = new EmbedBuilder()
            .WithDescription($":white_check_mark: {user.Mention} was unbaned")
            .WithFooter(footer =>
            {
                footer
                .WithText("User Unban Log");
            });
        Embed embed = EmbedBuilder.Build();
        await InfoChannel.SendMessageAsync(embed: embed);

        //Loging unbans//

        ITextChannel logChannel = Context.Client.GetChannel(793188013848789042) as ITextChannel;
        var EmbedBuilderLog = new EmbedBuilder()
            .WithDescription($"{user.Mention} was unbaned\n**Moderator** {Context.User.Mention}")
            .WithFooter(footer =>
            {
                footer
                .WithText("User Unban Log");
            });
        Embed embedLog = EmbedBuilderLog.Build();
        await logChannel.SendMessageAsync(embed: embedLog);
```

Comment: Could you run your error message through google translate? It kind of looks like Czech, but not knowing the language I can't say and more people will be able to help if you translate it for us. Though I'm guessing you don't have sufficient permissions to perform the action of unban (based upon the minimálně Alfa which looks like minimally Apha?).

Comment: The "minimally Alfa" is inside joke on my server xD, but thx for your point i will translate it. I am sure that i have all permissions and the bot too cause my ban and kick command is working.

Comment: You can't get a guild user in a command param if they're not in the guild. For this to work you should take a user's ID as a command parameter and remove the ban for that id. Alternatively, you could store user information somewhere and then look up a string input against your records to find the user they're referencing.

Comment: Nice thanks I'll try

Answer (score 0):

like the 230Daniel said the user cant be found because he isnt anymore in range of the bot ( if the bot isnt on a other server with him on it )